# Image inside label xamarin forms

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, fonts, label

I need to insert an image inside a label in Xamarin forms.
Sample: "If you find this image <image.png> you win"

I tryied to convert my png to Font and use it as Span inside the label but I failed (I don't know how to use the ttf file in the span). Any other suggestion? I prefer to avoid html view

Comment: Labels aren't clickable.  Have you tried an ImageButton?

Comment: It was an example, I don't have to click the image. My problem is to put an image inside a text. Another example: "if you find this image <image.png> you win"

Comment: use a Layout container to combine the Label with an Image control, as @maxikraxi demonstrates

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest solution is a GestureRecognizer

```
      <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Click this image" />
            <Image Source="tapped.jpg" />
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="Image1" />
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        </StackLayout>
```

more info on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap

Comment: I don't have to click the image and in your sample the image is under the text, not in the middle.

Comment: if uf want it "inside" und can just use a grid

Comment: @SimonePittiglio so use the sample maxikraxi provided but remove the GestureRecognizer...